# Implementing Control Structures in Brainfuck

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines, brainfuck

For the uninitiated, [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) is a Turing-complete language with only 8 commands, all of which have literal equivalents in C:

```
bf    c
----------------------
>     ++ptr;
<     --ptr;
+     ++*ptr;
-     --*ptr;
.     putchar(*ptr);
,     *ptr=getchar();
[     while (*ptr) {
]     }
```

On any linux distro that has a package manager, you ought to be able to find and install the package `beef`, a Brainfuck interpreter so you can play along at home.

As you can see above, Brainfuck has but **one** control structure, `[…]` which translates to C as:

```
while (*ptr) { … }
```

Which gives you all the control of `IF VAR = 0 THEN GOTO 10` from BASIC.  The following will call `getchar()` until it returns `0`:

```
,    # *ptr = getchar();
[    # while (*ptr) {
  >,    # *(++ptr) = getchar();
]    # }
```

But what if I only want to read to a newline char `\n`?  After having some difficulty wrapping my brain around how this could be adapted to work as a simple `if` I came up with the following:

```
,            # *ptr = getchar();      /* store input                               */
----------   # *ptr -= 10;            /* test for \n by subtracting 10 before loop */
[            # while (*ptr) {         /* if *ptr == 0, last char read was \n       */
  ++++++++++   # *ptr += 10;          /*   wasn't \n, add 10 back to val under ptr */
  >,           # *(++ptr) = getchar();
  ----------   # *ptr -= 10;
]            # }
```

(If anyone has a better way of doing this, please let me know)

Now lets say I want to test break out of that loop on `\r` in addition to `\n`. How can I test for either, given that I only have one opportunity to break out of the loop? My goal is to be able to emulate `switch`, nested `if`s or `if/else if`s.

Comment: There can be _no_ serious question about such a brain-dead language. In fact, that's what it _should_ be called: Braindead :-)

Comment: @SCMadsen Here's "Hello World": `++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.`

Comment: can you tell us the result of >[><]  :-))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't take a look at the link yet, but I imagine that [AShelly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421347/implementing-control-structures-in-brainfk/3446215#3446215) is probably more universally useful...however, having not dared to let my fingers type out some Brainfuck before, I decided that now was as good of a time as any and was able to get the following, which I *think* works.

The second half is just for printing out what was captured by the first part. Also, I won't lie, my brain does indeed feel thoroughly "fucked" after having tried to work this out...A very aptly-named language, heh.

```
+
[
    >,
    ----------
    [
        ---
        [
            +++++++++++++
            >>
        ]
    ]

    <
    [
      >>
    ]
    <
]

++++++++++++
[
    <
]

>
[
    .>
]
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms) are algorithms to perform basic LOGICAL but complex operation for Brain F*ck :)

Comment: Link is dead =/

Answer (score 3):

See [this page](http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_bf_intro.html) for a description of how to start with the single BF control structure and define a series of increasingly complex sequences representing more sophisticated operations.